# Distribuir lista <li> em 3 colunas

Tags: css, lista

Estou tentando criar uma lista com 5 blocos, 4 230X140px e 1 de 250X280px ,porém os mesmos não ficam alinhados lado-a-lado de forma correta, estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ficassem assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

códigos:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="tile-high">0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    width: 230px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li.tile-high {
    width: 250px;
    height: 280px;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira é aplicar o float:left em todos os `<li>` e colocar a tag `<ul>` dentro de uma `<div>` de tamanho definido. Ficaria assim:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<ul>
    <li class="tile-high">0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    width: 720px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    width: 230px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li.tile-high {
    width: 250px;
    height: 280px;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente, basta remover o `:nth-child(odd)`do último seletor e envolver a lista numa DIV cuja largura some as dimensões de todas as caixas (mais bordas e paddings do box-model):

```css
div {
    width: 716px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    width: 230px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li.tile-high {
    width: 250px;
    height: 280px;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="tile-high">0</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```